# Why does Eclipse New Maven Project not list Spring Boot Starters?

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, maven, maven-central

I have the latest version of Eclipse and am creating a basic Spring Boot Web project.
When I use the New -> ... -> New Maven Project and use the dialog to browse Maven Central for the Spring-Boot-Starter-Web artifact it isn't listed.

Why is Eclipse not listing it?

The configured repository is https://repo1.maven.org/maven2 (Maven Central) which is where Spring-Boot-Starter-Web is meant to reside. (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web/2.2.4.RELEASE)

I know how to use https://start.spring.io/ to create a spring boot start application so my question is not about how to create one.

What I want to know is what is it about Eclipse, or Maven, that prevents the Spring Boot Starters showing up. I am concerned that there may be plenty of other artefacts that are not visible here and would like to understand the rational for this so I can anticipate what may not be visible.

I appreciate I'm assuming here that a logical reason exists and apologises if it has more to do with how Eclipse *feels* about things to do with Spring Framework.

Answer (score 2):

You can add in Eclipse from the `Help -> Eclipse Marketplace` the Spring tools plugin (probably you'll find a newer version of the plugin):
[image: spring too]

After install it, you'll be able to create a Spring Boot project managing the dependencies at creation time. Select `Spring Boot -> Spring Starter Project`:
[image: starter]
Then you can select which maven dependencies to add:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. I have this though tend to use Spring Initializr at https://start.spring.io/. Creating spring boot projects isn't really a problem. My main interest here is in understanding what it is about Eclipse and Maven that stops it listing the spring boot starts from Maven Central. A previous suggestion is that the spring boot artifices are configure in some way that they are not listed. If this is so then I'm curious what this configuration is.

Answer (score 0):

it lists certain Maven archetype which Spring Boot starters aren't.
It's that simple.

Also, if you have archetypes (e.g. your company makes its own) you can add them to the list of archetypes known to your IDE.

Comment: Okay but what is it about the certain Maven archetypes that results in them being listed? What do they have that the spring boot ones lack, or what do the spring boot ones have that excludes them from being listed?

Comment: How do you add them?